# Windows Azure: Bypass load balancing and send request to specific VM

Tags: azure, load-balancing

I'll admit off the bat that this is an odd question and really makes no sense in most situations.  That being said, we just started using DevExpress's spreadsheet component and found out that an "image" of the document is stored in the web server's RAM and changes to the document send little requests to the web server to update the cell we are working with.

Obviously this is a massive problem with you have 10 instances of your app running in Azure as if a request is sent to a different server other than the one that was used to initially create the document, it won't be there to edit.  Is there any way to bypass the load balancer and just for certain requests related to the spreadsheet component, ensure that they go to the same web server?

Before anyone blows up saying that this completely defeats the concept of load balancing, I understand that, just trying to see if we can salvage the work we have done.

Comment: You could try enabling "Source IP Affinity" on the Azure load balancer. Each individual client will always go back to the same server, so it's not as fine-grained as you would like, but it should make the scenario work. Link: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/30/azure-load-balancer-new-distribution-mode/

Comment: Thanks for that.  Are there any downsides to this approach?  Is there any way to conditionally do this? Meaning, only do it for a certain set of requests and not for every request to an app?

Comment: This should be asked on ServerFault, not StackOverflow. That said: Endpoints may be direct-mapped to specific VMs without being load-balanced (you'll see this when you create it).

Comment: I believe you would need some variety of cookie-based load balancing to support that which Azure doesn't support natively as far as I can tell. That said, I've seen a few references to people "hacking" around that by using Application Request Router, so this might be something you could try out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2013/09/19/advanced-cookie-based-session-affinity-with-application-request-routing.aspx